# Inkscape: How to force a text or other shape to fill the interior of a closed path?

Tags: inkscape

[image]

See those red shapes. I want to crunch text BWT into the red area so that the text is still readable but deformed so that the red area is filled.

I have tried to use the black stroke-only version of the red shape as a bounding box (=a path effect) but it only makes a rectangular blob around the BWT without affecting its form.

Path effect Bounding Box maybe is not the right way or I do not understand how to use it. Any idea how do it right?

Comment: Most often it's easier to copy an existing shape and edit the copy to retain a contour which matches the original shape. Often any "bounding box" is not really that helpful. I don't know Inkscape.. but I'm sure someone will answer who does.

Comment: Thanks.... the shape I am editing has many points. so it just looks.... terrible when I try and do it that way.

Comment: Adding a screenshot might help answers.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE.  Can you please post an image showing the shape, and what you have tried/what has failed. It's almost impossible to answer questions like this without seeing what you are actually trying to achieve. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for having me. I have... no idea how to add a screen shot. give me a moment.

Comment: Thank you for recommending that I add the image. So what I would like to do is in those red closed paths, I would like that BWT to fill that space. I would like the contours of the BWT to mirror the contours of the shape.

Comment: oooooh.. that's completely different than what I thought you were asking. Screenshot helps a great deal.

Comment: Scott...sorry. I knew i was not actually saying what I was asking for.

Comment: You could use the Envelope Deformation path effect to distort the text.

Comment: Yes.... the envelope is getting me in the correct direction. but the transformation looks..... terrible. Billy Kerr, any suggestions?

Comment: Billy Kerr.. I can get much better results if I do it with the the tools and manually line it up each side.. This is a much better than I have been achieving. But  the power of these tools tells me that there must be a way the processor can do it.

Comment: I consider this answered ... how do I mark it as answered?

Comment: I've added an answer now. You can accept an answer by clicking the "check mark" button underneath the vote buttons. Of course, you don't have to accept my answer. Other's may have a better solution. Perhaps give it a day or two to see if anything better is suggested.

Comment: Envelope Tool is perfect. And only toggling the left and right side got me what I was looking. You just have to work it to maintain the ratio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several methods possible.

1. You could use the Envelope Deformation path effect to distort text which has been converted to paths in Inkscape.
2. Another possibility is the Lattice Deformation path effect.

These are both available in the Live Path Effects Selector

[image]

Both these path effects are quite tricky to apply, so you will have to experiment.  They're not perfect.  These are also very new features in Inkscape, so hopefully the Inkscape devs will be able in time to improve their usability.

If after making the transformations there are still some wonky lines that you'd like to fix, you can do *Path > Object to Path* to remove the effects, then edit the paths manually.

3. There was at one time a Bézier Envelope extension. Unfortunately the extension doesn't work in Inkscape 1.0 as far as I know, at least I couldn't get it to work. I even tried to get this to work with 0.92, but no joy. Maybe install Inscape 0.48 and try it out. The extension is [here](https://github.com/shlomif/Bezier-Envelope-for-Inkscape). There's a good tutorial for using this extension on youtube [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ldbdhVWaT20&feature=emb_logo).
4. If you have access to Adobe Illustrator, it also has an Envelope Mesh feature which is a little easier to use. Although again still not perfect, and also can be quite tricky to use.